# Passing reference_wrapper instead of a reference into a std::thread and into std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, ref

Reference_wrapper is a class wrapper around a pointer. I miss some basic information on the motivation, why reference_wrapper was introduced and Im trying to find it out with the following questions:

1. What would be wrong with passing a simple pointer into std::thread as an argument ?
2. Compiler doesn't allow to pass a reference to an object to std::thread. Why, what would go wrong under the hood, if a simple reference (address) were accepted (I dont mean passing by reference) ?
3. I know that types to be stored in stl containers must meet CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible requirements (and thats what refrence_wrapper does) and I think that this is mainly because of resizing/restoring the container, namely std::vector. However, lets say that resizing doesnt take place in our case, would it be correct to store references then ?
4. what is the advantage of storing a reference_wrapper into a stl container over a simple pointer ? Is it only that we know, that the vector doesnt own the objects pointed by reference_wrapper and we have to delete it separately (instead of pointers, where ownersip is ambiguous) ?

Comment: 1. It's perfectly fine to pass pointers to `std::thread`. 2. It's because `std::thread` takes arguments by value, and references are not copyable. `std::reference_wrapper` just holds a pointer under the hood.

Comment: _"if a simple reference (address)"_ But a reference is **not** an address. You can see it as an alias (no matter how it is really implemented, if it uses pointers or not, etc... should not matter, it's implementation details of the language)

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please?

Comment: @Fareanor as far as I know, a references are finally replaced by the compiler with the address of the referenced object in the code

Comment: @Fareanor 1) why ref() is commonly used instead of a simple pointer then, when passing pointers is perfectly fine ? Thats what Im missing.

Comment: @Tomas_cz It is not required by the standard, they can do anything (hence why `sizeof` of a reference cannot give anything meaningful). But anyway, what the compiler does to implement the language is none of our business. A reference and a pointer from the C++ perspective are two distinct, separate and different things. For instance, you can't have a null reference.

Comment: People might use `std::ref` for convenience, because it provides an interface to use it as if you had a reference (i.e. you do not need to dereference it, which could make the code clearer or simply reflect more the intention of the author to use a reference).

Answer (score 2):

1. Pointers can be `nullptr`. A pointer is no replacement for a reference nor vice versa.
2. Its not the compiler. Its by design that parameters are passed by value to threads constructor
3. `std::vector` is a template. Member methods only get instantiated when actually called. You might get away with constructing a vector whose element type does not meet all requirements, but it might be not that useful. The details are rather involved and I consider them to be too broad for the scope of this question. A `std::reference_wrapper` can be stored in a `std::vector` without any issues.
4. see 1. pointers are not replacement for references. They have different semantics. `std::reference_wrapper` is most likely just a pointer under the hood, but it does behave like a reference. And thats what you want when you want a reference.

Comment: Regarding 2) what would go wrong if a reference is passed instead of reference_wrapper, why is it not allowed ?

Comment: @Tomas_cz nothing would go wrong, because the constructor would use the value, ie make a copy. If the constructor would assume its all references *then* bad things would happen.

Comment: @Tomas_cz the object would be copied into a new value. That's how `std::thread` is specified to work. You *are* allowed to pass a reference to `std::thread::thread`

Comment: @Tomas_cz think of it like a lambda and the parameters you pass as the captures. Alwaays capturing everything by reference would lead to bad bugs. Always capturing everything by reference would be ok but less efficient. Thats why you get to choose

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "ok" there assumes you don't want to be able to mutate things

Comment: @Tomas_cz maybe you are looking for a case that absolutely needs `std::ref`, that cannot be done without. But thats not what motivates a good tool. A good tool makes a common task that would be difficult without the tool into something easy.

Comment: @Caleth yes, only speculative "would be ok" in the sense of not leading to difficult bugs but very limited in use

Comment: Nitpick for 3: every container requires *Erasable*, which requires `T*` be a type

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `std::thread`'s constructor can only accept references as input parameters; but eventually all the referenced objects are copied to the thread's local buffer(head of stack), prior to calling the worker function.
The reason is simple: the reference might outlive its referenced object, which leads to runtime errors. This can happen if thread manager object is stored in a container that outlived the thread's construction scope or if the thread is detached.
Any code that needs to artificially transfer a reference (such as `reference_wraper`) to a thread is fishy, and should be avoided.
Raw C pointers are troublesome relics that modern C++ does not recommend in user code base. If you need a pointer anywhere inside your code(not just the special case of threads), you may consider using smart pointers (`std::uniqe_ptr`,`std::shared_ptr`,...).

One final tip: prefere `std::jthread` over `std::thread`; the former joins automatically on destruction, which is a better guarantee for RAII.